# uislider padding not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui-slider

I am using uislider and it works great, but it sends the image across the entire width of the page. I attempted to change the javascript with no help. Finally I was able to get the right side of the page to pad properly using max-width: size of the image;

I've tried using min-width for the left side of the page, but it just doesn't seem to work.

**CSS:**

```
.banner {
       float: center;
       padding-top: 70px;
       padding-left: 160px;
       width: 100%;
       max-width: 895px;}

.banner ul li {
       float: left;}

   .banner li {
       list-style: none;}
```

Site is: mydiscountman.com if you want to see it functioning broken. I tried posting an image, but I do not have a reputation of 10 yet.

Thanks!

**Banner code:**

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="//mydiscountman.com/mdm-content/themes/clipper/js/unslider.js"></script>

<div class="banner">
     <ul>
        <li>
       <img src="http://mydiscountman.com/mdm-content/themes/clipper/images/bannertest.png"     width="895" height="294" title alt="social-facebook-color">
    </li>
    <li>
    <img src="http://mydiscountman.com/mdm-content/themes/clipper/images/bannertest2.png" width="895" height="294" title alt="social-facebook-color">
    </li>
    <li>
    <img src="http://mydiscountman.com/mdm-content/themes/clipper/images/bannertest3.png" width="895" height="294" title alt="social-facebook-color">
    </li>
</ul>

    <script>

    $(function() {
        $('.banner').unslider();
    });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`float: center;` is not a valid css property

`padding` is also considered as the width

eg if width is `100%` and `padding` is `10%` so the total `width` will be `110%`

if you want to add some space to the left use `margin` which will give space without effecting the `width`

Comment: That did it. OMG. Thank you!

  .banner {
        padding-top: 70px;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 895px;
        margin:0 160px;
        }